# OpenLiberty maven plugin & EAR project: Ignored exclusions of transitive dependencies in ear.xml

Tags: maven, maven-plugin, open-liberty

**Setup**

- Maven EAR project
- OpenLiberty plugin for local test deployment in a Liberty server

**Behaviour of the plugin**

The plugin deploys an XML file which aggregates a list and links to required runtime jars, instead of building an EAR file -- so far, so good, the application starts and runs.

**Issue**

However, some dependencies in the project have colliding transitive dependencies and the pom.xml contains a lot of exclusions. Unfortunately, those exlusions are ignored by the plugin and the application encounters runtime issues due to the aformentioned clashes (ClassNotFoundException etc.). Those -- of course -- do not occur, if one drops in the EAR file.

**Questions**

1. Is there a possibility to fix this issue and make the *.ear.xml contain those exclusions?
2. If not, is there a possibility to explicitly make the plugin build and use the EAR artifact instead of the implicitly generated xml file?

Comment: What version of liberty-maven-plugin are you using?  Have you tried the latest, e.g. v3.9?  I believe we've made a few fixes in a possibly-related area not too long ago.

Comment: Yes, I am using the very latest version i.e. 3.9

Comment: OK, please open an issue on the plugin GitHub repo:  https://github.com/OpenLiberty/ci.maven/issues/new   As documented here: https://github.com/OpenLiberty/ci.maven/blob/main/docs/deploy.md  you can switch to deploying the full binary EAR by adding plugin configuration `<looseApplication>false</looseApplication>`.  This "loose application" term is what we use to describe the app archive defined via XML like you described, though the name isn't obvious.  It's a slower iterative development cycle since you have to repackage now, but it is still usable.  Thanks for the question.

Comment: Thanks a lot for that extremely swift response. I will gladly open a ticket. So, do I understand correctly, that -- as such -- the plugin should by default (without any further, explicit config.) correctly recognize the dependency exclusions declared in the pom.xml? One more information: the project uses maven-ear-plugin

Comment: Should it recognize the exclusions?  Well, it's at least definitely a reasonable question to ask.  I'm not going to commit right here and now to saying "yes it should" but we can discuss as we look at the issue.  It might help to get a feel for what your dependencies look like.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Bypassing "loose application" and generating a normal archive file

To answer one part of your question, you can configure the liberty-maven-plugin to deploy the full binary archive (WAR or EAR) rather than use the XML-defined representation via the `<looseApplication>false</looseApplication>` parameter on your **liberty-maven-plugin** configuration:

```xml
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>io.openliberty.tools</groupId>
                <artifactId>liberty-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.9</version>
                <configuration>
                    <looseApplication>true</looseApplication>
            ...
```

This will be less convenient for iterative development, since you have to do a full "package" and then another "deploy" rather than only having to do another "compile", but it would be a way to work around the issue you discovered.

#### Follow-up

As far as the issue with the liberty-maven-plugin not handling exclusions in building the loose application XML file, I suggest opening an issue in the liberty-maven-plugin GitHub repo (https://github.com/OpenLiberty/ci.maven/) and I'll update this when we have one.